# Quantum Entanglement communication from bunker

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-entanglement

When a proton is entangled with its pair when one measures a spin state the other measures an opposite. While this technique cannot be used for superluminal communication (communication across time) but can be used for communication across space.

The idea is that this method can be used as a communication system for locations not accessible by satellite and without laying communication infrastructure? For example, underground bunkers deep beneath a mountain when communication links are physically destroyed or underwater submarines deep under the ocean without having to surface a communication buoy?

As with ongoing research into quantum radar, could one put a pair of an entangled proton at an underground base or underwater submarine and one at a command center. Based on the spin state of the proton at the base, you know the spin state at an underground bunker. Is this possible in theory and implementation? How many protons can be done this way to what bandwidth? Is there such research or is there possibly classified research done into this?

Comment: you cannot exploit entanglement for communication (superluminal or otherwise) without also having a classical communication channel or without being able to physically send the states over to the other party. The act of measuring one side of an entangled pair does not send any kind of information to the other party

Comment: I thought the act of measuring of one pair implies that the other would be in an opposite state. Like if I measure an "up" outside the bunker, it would be a "down" inside the bunker ?

Comment: that can happen for some states, yes, but there is no way to decide whether you'll see up or down when you measure, hence this is just a correlation, not something that you can use as a transmission medium